# python default dict memory leak

Tags: python, memory-leaks

I'm not sure if it is a memory leak but looks like one and I cannot find a solution here.
I cannot paste the full code but here is the part that leaking:

```
self.dctSpreads = defaultdict(list)

lstMat = ['2Y','3Y','4Y','5Y','6Y','7Y','8Y','9Y','10Y','12Y','15Y','20Y','25Y','30Y']

lstSpreads = ['A','B','C','D','E']

def __GetSpreadMDValues__(self):
        lstSpreadRIC = []
        lstSpreadVal = []

        #Construct proper RICs to extract the data
        for i in range(0, len(self.lstSpreads)):
            for j in range(0, len(self.lstMat)):
                lstSpreadRIC.append(self.lstMat[j])
            #get market data
            lstSpreadVal = self.__GetListDataSnaps__('FIELD1', lstCSASpreadRIC)
            self.dctSpreads[self.lstSpreads[i]] = lstCSASpreadVal
            lstSpreadRIC = []
            lstSpreadVal = []
```

the problem is that `self.dctSpreads` (which is dictionary of list with floating values) increase memory usage but never release it after I done working with the class object. I have tried writing a simple destructor like calling method

```
def Destructor(self):
        gc.collect()
```

before finishing my run but that did not help.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Only use `__` double-underscore names for Python special method names and values, don't arbitrarily invent your own. Private methods should only use `__` as a prefix, not as a postfix.

Comment: How are you "done" with the class object?

Comment: thnx for reply Martijn, this is only part of the code and __ here indicated method private to the class.

Comment: Also, just loop directly over lists, no need to use `range()`: `for spread in self.lstSpreads:` and `for mat in self.lstMat:` then `lstSpreadRIC.append(mat)`. `range()` also starts from 0 by default.

Comment: @ilyaw77: then remove the trailing `__` of the name.

Comment: "done" with the object, exiting main where object created.

Comment: And why use a `defaultdict` when you are not using the default value here? `defaultdict` is just a subclass of `dict` that materializes the default when the key isn't present, but you are ignoring that by assigning directly.

Comment: How are you measuring memory usage?  Even if Python is freeing the memory properly, the C runtime may not return the allocated virtual address space back to the OS, so to the OS it appears to be leaking memory when in fact it's not.

Comment: for spread in self.lstSpreads: thnx will do :) my background mostly C++ and VBA, just learning python now...

Comment: how are you sure that your some_sort_of_financial_class instance is not being referenced anymore?

Comment: "why use a defaultdict?" I tried dict as well, same problem

Comment: How are you measuring memory usage? - simply using task manager.

Comment: @ilyaw77: If you wish to indicate that a method should be treated privately, use a single underscore before the name. Also, `lstSpreadRIC` is basically just duplicating `lstMat`, you don't need to keep doing this.

Comment: @Joel Cornett, Joel, the RIC is composed of lstMat members and some const strings, just for simplicity I tok it out, sorry for misleading.

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between when Python will make unused memory available for use by your Python script and when it gets returned to the OS. The former happens immediately when there are no references to an object (assuming CPython) and the latter may not happen until the Python interpreter exits, depending on the type of objects allocated. This is normal and expected behavior.

Comment: thank you for reply. Looks like most of the people thinking it is expected behaviour. THe problem is the program run every 30 seconds, and the process keep growing. Do you think if I replace dict logic by more simple types (may be lists) will it help?

Comment: If the program runs every 30 seconds, why not just have it exit when it's done one loop, and have `cron` or whatever run it periodically?

Comment: that is exactly how it works now. It is open on a separate thread which run the program, wait until all files are getting saved, sleep for 20 seconds, and start running again. thrd = threading.Thread(target=MyPub), thrd.start(), thrd.join(60), time.sleep(20)